# Best way to capture data from ajax and manipulate with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a that should get images from database with ajax and then display it with some carousel plugin. Here is how it should work :

1. Image url is saved to database from admin
2. frontend script makes a ajax call to a php file and returns all url's from db.
3. Now when I have all images, the carousel plugin can be applied.
4. Images are now being displayed one by one.

The trick is that i want to make another ajax call when last image is displayed and repopulate container div with fresh images from database. Here is my code

```
function get_images(){
var data = {
    "function_name" : "get_images",
    "args" : ""
};

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost/.../functions.php",
    data : data,
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function(ret){
        $(".container").html(ret);
        $(".container").carousel(//When last call - function again);

    }
});
}
```

And here is the problem. On ajax success carousel plugin is starting to rotate imgs, and when its finished, the get_images function should be call again. But this function is already in the another function and every time when it makes a call it will be one level deeper. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be for the carousel to fire an event that it needs more images and listen to that event. You can then retrieve more images and return the new list to the carousel. There are carousel plugins that have all this build in. I often use this one: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your PHP script:

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['function_name']) ) {
        if ( $_POST['function_name'] == 'get_images' ) {
            // Get some URLs into an array...
            // For the sake of the example we'll manually fill the array
            $urls = ['img/image1.png', 'img/image2.png'];
            echo json_encode($urls);
        }
    }
```

And in your JS:

```
function Carousel() {
    this.getMoreImages();
}

Carousel.prototype.nextImage = function () {
    if (this.i < this.images.length) {
        this.showImage(); // Implement this.
        this.i += 1;
        this.spin():
    }
    else {
        this.getMoreImages();
    }
}

Carousel.prototype.spin = function () {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.nextImage();
    }, 5000);
}

Carousel.prototype.getMoreImages = function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost/.../functions.php',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (ret) {
            self.images = JSON.parse(ret);
            self.i = 0;
            self.spin();
        }
    });
}

var myCarousel = new Carousel();
```

This Carousel object will request an array of images on instantiation, and show each image on a 5-second interval. When all the images have been exhausted, it will automatically make another AJAX call, retrieving images in the same manner as it did originally, and then continue looping through the new images. It will continue in this cycle forever.